# How to quantise a bipolar analog signal using an ADC with lowest amount of signal noise

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, signal-processing

I have a linear position sensor that outputs an analogue signal between -4v and +4v corresponding to the position that I want to capture using an ADC and microcontroller.

It has a maximum resolution of 0.75um over a 9mm range which means that the ADC needs to be able to quantise 0.00067v steps which can be achieved using a readily available 16 bit ADC.

The problem that I am having is that the ADC can only take an input between 0v to 3.3v which means I will need to alter the signal coming from my sensor so that it can work with my ADC.

My idea was to first use a summing amplifier setup to bias the signal so that it is in the 0 to 8v range then use a potential divider to split the signal so that it will be in the 0 to 3.3v range like in the diagram below

[image: Circuit diagram]

This works in simulation however, I am unsure if this is the best way to approach this problem and what level of noise will be added to the signal which consequently will affect the accuracy in the position measurement.

Comment: Opamps should be rail-to-rail inputs/outputs ...

Comment: Assuming the Opamps are rail to rail, is that all that I would need to get the same level or accuracy as the sensor?

Comment: At least, you should have the same "accuracy" and/or "stability" of all the resistors ... which would be "quasi" impossible ...

Comment: Assuming i use 0.1% resistors and a trimmer for the voltage divider so that I can maximise the ADC range do you think this is a sensible way to approach this problem.

Comment: With 0.1% resistors, the error should be at "0.001" (relative), without "offsets" .... of opamps and some other errors.